# Insert stored procedure output data into a column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server. The stored procedure subtracts two columns in the same table. How do I insert this stored procedure data into a Inventory column of the dbo.Store table? The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp.StoreBilling]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Stock decimal(10,2)=0.00
    DECLARE @Spoilage decimal(10,2)=0.00

    SELECT A.Stock, A.Spoilage, A.Stock-A.Spoilage AS Inventory
    FROM dbo.Store AS A
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table, or use an existing one easily.

```
create table #BillingResult
(
    Stock int
    , Spoilage int
    , Inventory int
)

insert #BillingResult
exec [dbo].[sp.StoreBilling]
```

Comment: thank you all for the responses. How do I insert the stored procedure data into an existing table - dbo.Store?

Comment: Change the insert statement to insert into that table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert into a newtable such as this

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp.StoreBilling]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Stock decimal(10,2)=0.00
    DECLARE @Spoilage decimal(10,2)=0.00    

    INSERT INTO NewTabeName(Stock, Spoilage, StockChange)
    SELECT A.Stock, A.Spoilage, A.Stock-A.Spoilage AS Inventory
    FROM dbo.Store AS A
END
```